# I am trying to detect if a user executes lua code before mine

Tags: lua, roblox

How would i detect if a user executes any code before my code? Ive tried this:

```lua
setmetatable(getfenv(), {

    __newindex = function(t,i,k)
      print(t,i,k)
    end
})

print("a")
```

and it doesn’t detect, im using this to make a whitelist for roblox so i am trying to prevent people from executing debuggers before it

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If other code runs before your code, *it* can sandbox *you* and you'd never know. Also, generally if you're trying to implement anti-debugging, you're doing something that you shouldn't.

Comment: Im trying to make a whitelist for a roblox cheat, so i am trying to prevent debugging of the whitelist

Comment: The best thing you can do is putting your whitelist into a local. Not safe either but at least harder to read.